# SSRS 2008- user type in multiple values as parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that has a user type in parameter, where the user can type in the input. I want the user to enter multiple values separated by a comma.

E.g.: PrimaryName- balcksmith,whitesmith,smith,etc,etc

Is this possible?

I have also tried using the Split function. But no use. Does the split function work with Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

I have done this as a set of default parameters on a linked report (see [here](http://faultbucket.ca/2011/04/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-in-linked-report/) on my blog),
and it should be as simple as entering your values one after each other on a separate line.

Instead of:

```
blacksmith,whitesmith,smith
```

Use:

```
blacksmith
whitesmith
smith
```